# Cancel previous backend request if a new one is created

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, angular6

I need to create an Angular component to allow the user to select a city with a type suggestion.

When the user has typed three or more characters, the frontend asks the backend for a list of cities whose names begin with the user input.

After that I pass to the mat-option component an Observable of the list of the cities

```
searchCities = (value: string): Observable<City[]> => {
    if(value.length >= this.minCityNameLength){
      return this.detailsITService.fetchCitiesByName(value);
    }

    return of([]);
};
```

Is there a way to "cancel" a request if the method `searchCities` (passed as an input parameter to my custom component) is called with new user input?

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: I dont think that you can cancel request once its made, but you can use buffer() and filter to combine and reduce overhead of calls. You can buffer to hold the network call until some point, and filter to make sure inputs are validated

Comment: @Talha Yes, the HttpClient in Angular can actually cancel requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typeahead is a pretty common problem, and rxjs a wonderul tool to deal with this. Let's assume `input$` is an observable emitting the search string the user entered, you can do it like this:

```js
input$.pipe(
  // This is optional, just a suggestion. It prevents a
  // request from being started while the user is still
  // quickly typing a word. The value is a time in ms, see
  // the operators docs for details.
  debounceTime(250),

  // Here's the actual piece of code: switchMap will
  // start a new inner subscription whenever a new search
  // input comes along, cancelling any still on-going previous
  // request. This avoids any race conditions.
  switchMap(input => input.length > this.minCityNameLength
    ? this.detailsITService.fetchCitiesByName(input)
    : of([])
  )
).subscribe(…);
```

The way you set up the `input$` stream would, for example, be with

```
<input type="text" (input)="input$.next($event.target.value)" />
```

where `input$` is defined as

```js
public input$ = new Subject<string>();
```

You can find a working example [here](https://rxviz.com/v/lJ06eKzo). You can also see the effect `debounceTime` has in there if you open the console and try it with and without the operator.

Comment: This is the solution that is widely used in rx, I had same case implementing this using rxjava!
I mistakenly wrote buffer in above comment instead of debounce!